# "tiger's numbers keep growing“ vs ”tigers' number keeps growing“

Tags: word-usage

Which is more acceptable?

I have found quite a few examples like "the panther's numbers are expected to hit...",

Can a specific figure be called "numbers" and be used as a plural form?

Shouldn't the word **number** be used mostly as a singular word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this phrase used on [WWF](http://wwf.panda.org/what_we_do/endangered_species/tigers/news_pubs/?212650/Leonardo-DiCaprio-Foundation-to-help-WWF-double-Nepals-tiger-population) website -

> Previous support from the Leonardo DiCaprio Foundation is already showing major results, **growing the number of tigers** in the Terai’s Bardia National Park from an estimated 18 to 50 tigers.

I feel that's quite appropriate way of telling that the population of tigers keeps growing. When you mean that their population is increased, you use *number* and *tigers.* No matter what, if something grows from 1 to 100, it's the *number increased* and not *numbers*. So, the *number* of *tigers* grow, not the *numbers of tiger*.

However, *numbers* is also possible (see the same article) where different surveys come with their different numbers which may be then totaled to come to a conclusion. If you precisely look at tiger's number, you may think of giving number to the tigers like Tiger No. 1, 2, 3 and so on!

Answer (score 4):

This is a special plural-only usage of the word *number*, meaning, basically, *statistics*. See [Merriam-Webster's sense 8b for *number*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/number)

> `statistics` 2; *especially*: individual statistics (as of an athlete)

where *statistics* sense 2 is:

> `statistics` 2: a collection of quantitative data

Answer (score 0):

First, there is the question of "tiger's" or "tigers'".  Of course we are talking about more than tiger, but the singular "the tiger" can be used idiomatically to refer to tigers in general.  I think if you're talking about all tigers, "the tiger's numbers are growing" could be ok in that sense.  If it is a specific group of tigers, "the tigers' numbers are growing" seems preferable.

As for "numbers", I think the key definition from [Merriam Webster "number"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/number) is 1a(4): "*(plural)*: a numerous group."  Their "numbers" is their numerous group.  To say "their numbers are growing" means their numerous group is growing (in number).

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for contributing. Countability of nouns, and omission of the article, inform a great many questions here.